# Roll up child elements in nested jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

When using jQuery's Accordion (in a nested fashion), I want to ensure that when a parent element is clicked/opened, any open children are closed/rolled up.  I'm not sure what selector(s) I should use when attempting to do this.  So far I've tried rigging a change event with "activate" set to false, but that simply makes any element that is opened automatically close.

Assuming I only have 1 nested accordion, my jquery initialization looks like:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
            active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false, animated: 'swing'
        });

        $(".child-accordion").accordion({
            active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false, animated: 'swing',
            change: function(event, ui) { $(".child-accordion").accordion("activate", false); }
        });
```

where .child-accordion is the nested instance.  I need anything under the .child-accordion to be closed when a member of the .accordion is opened.

Comment: should the change event be on the .accordion class instead?..

Comment: I tried that, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    animated: 'swing',
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
        child.accordion("activate", false);
    }
});

var child = $(".child-accordion").accordion({
    active:false,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    animated: 'swing'
});
```

The reason your version wasn't working is two-fold

1. Your change event needs to be on the parent, because that's when you want the children to roll up
2. You need to make the event `changestart` because when you set `activate` to false, the main thing it does is `toggle` the currently "visible" section in the child, but when the `change` event triggers on the parent, the child is already hidden, so it doesn't do anything.

**EDIT**: here's a working version of this http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/YPpEn/

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for.